# Traduire « pettifogging »

Tags: traduction, anglais

En anglais pettifogging est défini comme étant « Placing undue emphasis on petty details » et « to bicker or quibble over trifles or unimportant matters ».

Quel mot français pourrais être utilisé pour signifier la même chose avec une connotation similaire ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Pinailler* est à ajouter aux propositions de Circeus (et plus courant dans mon entourage qui emploie peu *ergoter* et *chicaner*).

Answer (score 8):

*Ergoter*, *chicaner* et *couper des cheveux en quatre*, ainsi que leurs familles, sont les premiers termes qui me viennent à l'esprit.